# How to structure modules to avoid things like "import module.module.module"

Tags: python, module, package

I have a module structured as follows:

```
/module
    __init__.py
    /submod_1
        __init__.py
        submod_1_class.py
    /submod_2
        __init__.py
        submod_2_class.py
```

but I find it incredibly annoying to have to import a class within `submod_1_class.py` with:

```
from module.submod_1.submod_1_class import my_class
```

What I would prefer to be able to type is:

```
from module import my_class
```

I have browsed through the `site-packages` folder and looked through popular modules like `numpy`, but I haven't been able to figure out how, for example:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

can be used when the definition of `numpy` array objects is buried deep within several subfolders of the `numpy` package.

Comment: Add some `__init__.py` files to define what should be accessible from each module. For example, if you have one in `/module` that includes `from submod_1.submod_1_class import class`, then from outside the module you *can* `from module import class`. To stick with `numpy`, for example, [this line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L192) means that everything defined in [this file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/__init__.py) can be imported straight from `numpy`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please put that in an answer, so you can get points for the upvote I want to give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__init__.py` files to define what can be `import`ed from a given module. A very simple addition to your structure, for example, would draw up `Class` from `submod_1_class` such that external users can simply `from module import Class`.

```
/module
    __init__.py
        from submod_1 import Class
    /submod_1
        __init__.py
            from submod_1_class import Class
        submod_1_class.py
    /submod_2
        submod_2_class.py
```

In `numpy`, for example, the top-level `__init__.py` contains [a line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L192) that reads:

```
from .core import *
```

This means everything defined within [`/core/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/__init__.py) is available externally directly in the `numpy` namespace, even though it may actually be buried deep in some complex structure.